# Solving the limit when approaching infinity of factorial functions

Tags: limits

I am struggling to find the solution of the following expression when $N$ approaches $\infty$. I believe the answer is 0 but my friend is convinced is that it is going to be 1.

$\cfrac{N(N-1)(N-2)\ldots 1}{(N+ \frac{1}{M})(N-1 + \frac{1}{M})(N-2 + \frac{1}{M})\ldots(1 + \frac{1}{M})}$

where $M$ is a constant.

My intuition is that each entry in the denominator is larger by $\cfrac{1}{M}$ therefore it is larger and therefore the answer is 0. I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted him to be correct. Posted here to get confirmation.

Comment: @quanticbolt What makes you think that? Take M=10 and N = 5000000. You get about 0.2. For M=2 it would be about 0.0004 with that value of N.

Comment: @quanticbolt increasing $N$ will just decrease the value

Comment: @almagest ahhhh wow. Yep, bad reading on my part. Disregard my earlier comments.

Comment: So what is the consensus then?

Comment: The limit is $0$. The sequence is asymptotic to $c \cdot N^{-1/M}$ for some $c > 0$.

Comment: @HassamUllahSheikh You think math is a matter of consensus? You have an answer proving that the answer is **not** 1. You have some numerical evidence that is compatible with it being 0. Beyond that all you had until just now was guessing. Now you have one person - who appears to have got a more precise answer but not posted a proof (but with his reputation he is probably correct),

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $\epsilon=1/M$, and assume $M>0$ therefore $\epsilon>0$. Then the first term is going to be $$a_1=\frac 1{1+\epsilon}$$ You have the recurrence relationship $$a_{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{n+1+\epsilon}a_n$$
Since $a_{n+1}<a_n$, you have a monotonically decreasing sequence. And since the first term is not greater than $1$, it means that the limit will always be less than $1$. I don't even need to calculate it (you will not have any terms greater than $1/(1+\epsilon)$)

Then just apply the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, and choose $$\varepsilon=\frac 1{2(1+\epsilon)}$$You cannot find any $\delta$ such that all terms with $N$ greater than $\delta$ will be in the interval $1-\varepsilon$ to $1+\varepsilon$

Comment: So, it will be 1 then? Excuse my lack of ignorance.

Comment: It cannot be $1$. The limit **must** be smaller than any of the terms, since it's a decreasing sequence. That means that if the first term is smaller than $1$, the limit will be smaller than $1$.

Comment: I'm not sure if the limit is zero (that would be my guess), but it's between $0$ and $1$, strictly less than the first (or any) term

Comment: Write it as $$\prod_{k = 1}^{N}\biggl( 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{k}\biggr)^{-1}\,.$$ Take the logarithm, sum it up using $\log (1 + x) = x + O(x^2)$. You get $$\prod_{k = 1}^{N}\biggl( 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{k}\biggr)^{-1} = \exp \bigl( -\epsilon \log N + C(\epsilon) + O(N^{-1})\bigr)\,.$$